# For every integer n, if n is greater than or equal to m, then n^5 - 1 is composite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Statement:
For every integer n, if n is greater than or equal to m, then n^5 - 1 is composite.
What is the smallest possible integer m > 1 to satisfy this statement?

Comment: HINT: What do you know about factoring $a^n-b^n$?

Comment: Hint: Try factoring the polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to realize that $n^5 - 1= (n-1)(n^4 + n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)$.  So if $p=n-1$ and $n^4 + n^3 + n^2 + n+1= q$ then $n^5 -1 = pq$.  Always.

The thing is $p = n-1$ *could* be equal to $1$ and $q = n^4 + n^3 + n^2 + n + 1$ *could be equal to $n^5-1$,  if $n = 2$.  (But we don't really have to worry about $n^4 + n^3+n^2 + n + 1 = 1$ and $n-1 = n^5-1$ if $n$ is positive.)

So as long as $p,q$ are integers (which they are if $n$ is) and, if $n > 0$, then so long as $n-1 \ne 1$  then $n^5 -1 = pq=(n-1)(n^4+n^3 + n^2+ n + 1$ is composite.

The whole "$n^5-1$ is composite for $n \ge m$ for what value of $m>1$" is just a convoluted way of saying "when is $n-1$ not equal to $1$".  And $n-1 > 1$ if $n> 2$ means the answer is.... $m =2$.

Answer (score 1):

It´s easy. you only factorize $n^5-1=(n-1)(n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1)$. In order that both factors be $\geq 2$ you only need that $n\geq3$

Comment: Plus $n=2$ does not work because $2^5-1=31$, a prime.

Comment: Yes, I omitted that obvious part

Comment: Hypothetically it could be that if $n = 2$ then $n-1 =1$ but it could *hypothetically* be that $n^4 +n^3 + n  +1=2^4 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2 + 1$ might be composite.  It *isn't* but it could be.  In which case the smallest $m$ is $2$.